# Index of Directed Union of Groups

Tags: group-theory, limits-colimits, directed-union

Let $I$ be a nonempty directed set, and $H_i \le G_i$ both be directed sequence of groups living in some ambient group. Is there a nice formula for $|\bigcup_{i \in I} G_i : \bigcup_{i \in I} H_i|$, perhaps involving a limit or supremum of the $|G_i : H_i|$? I must confess, I don't really have much intuition for what the index should be.

Comment: Let $G$ be the Prufer $p$-group, let $G_i$ be the subgroup of order $p^{i+1}$, and let $H_i$ be the subgroup of order $p^i$. Then $[G_i:H_i]=p$ for all $i$, but $\cup G_i=\cup H_i$, so the index is $1$. On the other hand, taking $G=P\times C_p$, where $P$ is Prufer $p$-group, letting $G_i$ be the product of the subgroup of order $p^i$ and $C_p$, and letting $H$ just be the subgroup of order $p^i$ (times the trivial subgroup) gives you all $[G_i:H_i]=p$, and $[\cup G_i:\cup H_i]=p$.

Comment: And we could do examples where the index increases without bound but the index of the "limits" is any particular value you want. I don't think you can say *anything* in general at all, except  that the index of the limits cannot be strictly larger than the suprema of the indices.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Ah, so $|\cup G_i : \cup H_i| \le \sup |G_i : H_i|$? That's actually helpful, because I can choose groups the groups $H_i \le G_i$ and hence control $\sup |G_i : H_i|$. You should turn your two comments into an answer; they were helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the best we can say is that $[\cup G_i:\cup H_i]\leq \mathrm{sup}\{[G_i:H_i]\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

Indeed, let $g_1,\ldots,g_n$ represent distinct cosets of $\cup H_i$ in $\cup G_i$. Then there exists an index $N$ such that $g_1,\ldots,g_n\in G_N$, and since $g_jH_N\subseteq g_j\cup H_ik$, it follows that the the $g_i$ represent distinct cosets of $H_N$ in $G_N$. Thus, $n\leq [G_N:H_N]\leq \sup\{[G_i:H_i]\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$.

But it is easy to come up with all kinds of examples where the inequality is strict. For example, we take subgroups of the Prüfer $p$-group whose union is the whole thing, and subgroups of them whose union is also the whole thing, but the indices are either constant, or even growing. So the supremum is whatever we want, from $1$ through $\infty$, but $[\cup G_i:\cup H_i]=1$. Simple tweaks give you $[\cup G_i:\cup H_i] = p^i$ for any $i$, even if the indices grow without bound, or are always $p^{i+1}$, etc.